# Sukkos Gedolim Poster

Tags: product-recommendation, sukkah, pictures, noy-decorations

A bit late to be asking but anyone know where to get this poster?:
[image]

Comment: I saw it at the Israel Bookshop in Brookline when I went to pick up my lulav holder. FWIW, I'm not a huge fan of the whole gedolim portraits thing, it seems a bit close to ע”ז to me.

Comment: http://seforim.blogspot.com/2013/08/r-shlomo-yosef-zevin-and-army-and-joe.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30211/discussion-between-danf-and-noach-mi-frankfurt).